# what is the meaning of `template<class int>` in c++?

Tags: c++, templates

I have read some code about graph. But I have a question about template in C++.

```
typedef int intT;

template <class intT>
struct edge {
  intT u;
  intT v;
  edge(intT f, intT s) : u(f), v(s) {}
};

template <class intT>
struct edgeArray {
  edge<intT>* E;
  intT numRows;
  intT numCols;
  intT nonZeros;
  void del() {free(E);}
  edgeArray(edge<intT> *EE, int r, int c, int nz) :
    E(EE), numRows(r), numCols(c), nonZeros(nz) {}
  edgeArray() {}
};
```

this code equals

```
struct edge {
  int u;
  int v;
  edge(int f, int s) : u(f), v(s) {}
};

...
```

And why is the `template<class int>` in this code ?

what is the difference between `template<class T=int>` and  `template<class int>` ?

There are two `intT`, one is `typedef int intT` , the other one is  `template< class intT>`, the scope of `intT` is different ??

---

update:

The name of a template parameter hides the same name from the outer scope for the duration of its own:

```
typedef int N;
template< N X, // non-type parameter of type int
          typename N, // scope of this N begins, scope of ::N interrupted
          template<N Y> class T // N here is the template parameter, not int
         > struct A;
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Comment: What to you mean by 'this code equals'? The first declaration of `edge` does not compile and the second does. So it's not clear what you mean.

Answer (score 6):

> And why is the `template<class int>` in this code ?

We can only guess here. Probably someone designed `edge` and `edgeArray` to hold values of type `int` (the builtin `int`!), then wanted to use templates instead and thought to be clever by naming the template parameter `int`. But, surprise, this doesn't compile since `int` is a keyword.

> what is the difference between `template<class T=int>` and `template<class int>` ?

```
template<class T=int>
```

declares a template with one template parameter called `T` that defaults to `int`. That means you can omit the template parameter and it will become `int` by default.

```
template<class int>
```

on the other hand declares a template with one template parameter named `int`. As mentioned above this doesn't compile.

Comment: The question has been edited. The code compiles now.

Comment: @chris Thanks for mentioning it. I think the core questions are still the same, though they don't match the code anymore and there's a completely new question at the end.

Comment: I know what the problem is. The scopes of `intT` do not affect each other. `template <class intT>` could be replaced with `template<class T>` .  Thank you.